# Error con LinkedList Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursión

tengo que unir dos linkedList ordenando sus valores y no consigo hacerlo, agradecería una mano

EL ejercicio es:

```
Implementar la función mergeLinkedLists que, a partir de dos listas simplemente enlazadas del mismo tamaño retorne una nueva lista con los elementos de ambas listas
Ejemplo:

    Lista 1: Head --> 1 --> 7 --> 20 --> null
    Lista 2: Head --> 4 --> 13 --> 2 --> null
    Lista nueva luego de aplicar mergeLinkedLists:
             Head --> 1 --> 4 --> 7 --> 13 --> 20 --> 2 --> null**

Nota: las listas enlazadas mergeadas intercalandose.
El nodo 1 de la lista 1, se conecta con el nodo 1 de la lista 2.
Continuando con el nodo 2 de la lista 2, conectandose con el nodo 2 de la lista 2.
```

La solución que intenté fue la siguiente:

```
merge(linkedListOne, linkedListTwo){
    var linkedListMerge = new Node (null, null);
    var previous = linkedListMerge;
    
    while(linkedListOne !== null && linkedListTwo !== null){
      if (linkedListOne.valor <= linkedListTwo.valor){
        previous.next = linkedListOne;
        linkedListOne = linkedListOne.next;
      }else{
        previous.next = linkedListTwo;
        linkedListTwo = linkedListTwo.next;
      }
      previous = previous.next;
    }
    if (linkedListOne === null){
      previous.next = linkedListTwo;
    }
    if (linkedListTwo === null){
      previous.next =linkedListOne;
    }
    return linkedListMerge;
  }
};
```

Tratando de unir ambas LinkedList pero no, no me sale. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que te saltas nodos. Supon el if primero: lista1->valor < lista2->valor. Entonces en previous.next apunta al nodo actual de lista1, pero ¿qué pasa con lista2?. creo que hay tendrías que pasar previous a previous.next y apuntarlo al nodo actual de  lista2. Igual en el otro if. No lo he comprobado sin las definiciones de las clases Nodo y ListaEnlazada, pero podría ser.

Comment: Pareciera que copiaste el código de una función que los une por su valor. En este caso no se te pide eso, sino simplemente unir el primero de la primer lista al primero de la segunda lista; el segundo de la primera al primero de la segunda y así sucesivamente. En otras palabras, no necesitas comprobar el valor. Es todavía mas simple hacer esto que lo que ya hiciste.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda? ¿Cuál es el error o problema de tu código? (Porque es tuyo, ¿cierto?). Te invito a repasar [ask] y [mcve]. Para poder ayudarte has de ser más explícito, explicando el problema o problemas, el comportamiento actual de tu código y el comportamiento esperado. Saludos